# Invalid input syntax for integer (error 500)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, coffeescript

I'm struggling with an issue and can't seem to find an answer on how to fix it. I've made a portion of code that locates a file and deletes it from a folder.
Problem is I always end up with this internal 500 error : **Invalid input syntax for integer delete**

Node JS code

```
Theme.delete = (fileName) ->
    new Promise((fulfill, reject) ->
      if process.env.TNU_ROOT_DIRECTORY
        path = process.env.TNU_ROOT_DIRECTORY + '/www/app/datas/data/' + fileName
      else
        path = '././uploads/' + fileName

      fs.unlink path, (err, items) ->
        if err
          reject err
        else
          fulfill items
        return
      return
    )
```

Remote Method to delete

```
Theme.remoteMethod 'delete',
    accepts: [
      { arg: 'fileName', type: 'object', required: true, http: {source: 'path'} }
      { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: source: 'req' }
      { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: source: 'res' }
    ]
    returns: [
      arg: 'fileName'
      type: 'object'
    ]
    http:
      verb: 'DELETE'
      path: '/delete/:fileName'
```

Angular Front Code

```
$scope.delete = (fileName) ->
      console.log(fileName)
      Theme.delete(fileName).$promise
      .then (response) ->
        $scope.status = fileName + ' Deleted Successfully'
        $scope.fileList = files
      .catch (error) ->
        $scope.status = 'KO: ' + error.data.error.message
```

HTML/Jade code

```
md-subheader.md-no-sticky(ng-show="fileList.length" layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="background-color:#ff5252; color:#000000") Uploaded files
md-list-item.make-scrollable(ng-repeat='item in fileList')
  p
    a(href="")  {{ item }} 
  p Document
  p Success
  md-button.md-icon-button.md-primary.md-hue-0.limitElipsis(ng-click="delete(item)")
    md-icon(md-menu-origin md-svg-icon="trash")
```

Is it possible to have an hint on how to move forward, please ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't these `->` be `=>` ?

Comment: According to linter's warnings, it should be -> but both don't really make a huge difference in the browser, for some weird reason.

Comment: CoffeeScript has `->`, it's function that does not bind to the current context and instead, has its own. Semantics for `=>` are the same as in ES6.